# Regular expression to find last integer on a line

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have this code:

```
23561623:page[1].12 
6461620:page[3].7 
43631619:page[1].1 
265461620:page[6].2 
21461621:page[1].10
```

I have to get the last integer like 12,7,1,2,10 etc. Can some one help to write a preg_match so I can get it?

Thanks in advance,
Lucky

Answer (score 7):

```
$str = '23561623:page[1].12';
$parts = explode('.', $str);
echo $parts[1];
```

And if you *must* use `preg_match` (even though it's unnecessary here):

```
$str = '23561623:page[1].12';
$matches = array();

if (preg_match('/\.(\d+)$/', $str, $matches)) {
    echo $matches[1];
}
```

Comment: I had to remove my answer because it was so inferior to this. +1!

Comment: Here's an explanation and visualization of the regular expression and the subject string: http://regex101.com/r/vL7fN9

Comment: Thank you so much. You are genius. It was quick and superb.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers seem to assume that there will always be a period; there might be, but the below doesn't make such an assumption.

If you have one block of strings like that, you can run this regular expression code:

```
if (preg_match_all('/(\d+)\s*$/m', $str, $matches)) {
    // $matches[1] contains all the integers
}
```

It matches the last set of digits (`(\d+)`) optionally followed by white-space (`\s*`) until the end of the line (`$`). The `/m` modifier makes `$` behave as end-of-line instead of end-of-subject.